# Inject property value with qualifiers using functionally defined BeanDefinitions

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm using Spring 6. Say I have the following beans defined somewhere in the application's classpath.

```java
// "A"-qualified Foo instances
@Bean @Qualifier("A") adventure () { return new Foo("Adventure"); }
@Bean @Qualifier("A") afternoon () { return new Foo("Afternoon"); }
@Bean @Qualifier("A") air       () { return new Foo("Air");       }
@Bean @Qualifier("A") animal    () { return new Foo("Animal");    }
@Bean @Qualifier("A") apple     () { return new Foo("Apple");     }
@Bean @Qualifier("A") award     () { return new Foo("Award");     }

// "B"-qualified Foo instances
@Bean @Qualifier("B") basket  () { return new Foo("Basket");  }
@Bean @Qualifier("B") bee     () { return new Foo("Bee");     }
@Bean @Qualifier("B") blanket () { return new Foo("Blanket"); }
@Bean @Qualifier("B") bicycle () { return new Foo("Bicycle"); }
@Bean @Qualifier("B") bucket  () { return new Foo("Bucket");  }
@Bean @Qualifier("B") button  () { return new Foo("Button");  }
```

With annotations hard-coded in a class file, I could normally autowire all "A"-qualified instances of `Foo` into a property like so:

```java
@Autowired
public void setFoos(@Qualifier("A") final List<Foo> foos) { 
   this.foos = foos;
}
```

Is it also possible to inject property values using a `Qualifier` when functionally registering `BeanDefinitions`? I'm thinking that if it was possible, it would look something like this:

```java
public void registerBar(final BeanDefinitionRegistry registry) {
    final BeanDefinition beanDefinition = (
        BeanDefinitionBuilder.genericBeanDefinition(Bar.class)
            .addPropertyValue ("id",  "bar_0001"),
            .addPropertyValue ("...", "...")
            .addPropertyValue ("foos", new QualifiedRuntimeBeanReference(Foo.class, "A"))
        .getBeanDefinition()
    );
   beanDefinitionRegistry.registerBeanDefinition("bar", beanDefinition);
}
```

It doesn't seem like what I'm asking about is supported in a straightforward way. I see a little bit of discussion that appears related in [the Spring Framework project on GitHub](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/23032), but the solution there doesn't seem to consider qualifiers.

Answer (score 0):

Well to answer my question: I've found a solution that makes it *possible* to do this, but it requires reflection. I'd certainly like to see a better solution!

```java
public void registerBar(final BeanDefinitionRegistry registry) {
    // Use reflection to get the writeMethod of property the class we want to autowire.
    final Method writeMethod;
    try {
        writeMethod = Bar.class.getMethod("setFoos", List.class);
    } catch (final NoSuchMethodException e) {
        throw new Error(e);
    }

    // Create an overriden instance of the MethodParameter to add the desired @Qualifier annotation to it.
    final MethodParameter writeMethodParameter = new MethodParameter(writeMethod, 0) {
        @Override
        public @NonNull Annotation[] getParameterAnnotations() {
            // Call the super method to get the existing annotations on the function, then add the desired
            // @Qualifier annotation to the list.
            Annotation[] annotations = super.getParameterAnnotations();
            annotations                         = Arrays.copyOf(annotations, annotations.length + 1);
            annotations[annotations.length - 1] = new Qualifier() {
                @Override
                public @NonNull String value() {
                    return "A";
                }

                @Override
                public Class<? extends Annotation> annotationType() {
                    return Qualifier.class;
                }

                @Override
                public String toString() {
                    return "@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(\"" + value() + "\")";
                }
            };

            // Use reflection to set the private parameterAnnotations field on the super class; this hack to 
            // funtionally declare a @Qualifier annotation does not work if the private field is not set.
            try {
                final Field field = getClass().getSuperclass().getDeclaredField("parameterAnnotations");
                field.setAccessible (true);
                field.set           (this, annotations);
            } catch (final NoSuchFieldException | IllegalAccessException e) {
                throw new Error(e);
            }

            return annotations;
        }
    };

    final BeanDefinition beanDefinition = (
        BeanDefinitionBuilder.genericBeanDefinition(Bar.class)
            .addPropertyValue ("id",  "bar_0001"),
            .addPropertyValue ("...", "...")
            .addPropertyValue ("foos", new DependencyDescriptor(writeMethodParameter, true))
        .getBeanDefinition()
    );

    beanDefinitionRegistry.registerBeanDefinition("bar", beanDefinition);
}
```